# How to create fixed mail in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

These days I send my CV every day to lots of contacts, such that each time I send the same mail but with different "To" address.

In order to avoid re-uploading the CV for each sent email, I uploaded the CV (doc file) to Google Drive and when I want to send it I do: `right click > Share > Email as attachment`.

Now, how could I create a fixed body for these mails instead of re-typing it each time?

Comment: Send the email to yourself, then just forward it (after deleting the forward part)

Comment: I'm looking for more generically way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gmail you can make templates.

To enable templates you have to use a Labs Feature called *canned responses*.

- Click the Gear Icon in the top right.
- Select Settings from the menu.
- Click on the Labs tab.
- Look for Canned Responses
- Enable It
- Make Sure you click "Save Changes" at the bottom

To Set Up a Template:

- Compose a new message as per normal.
- Once done, click on the more options dropdown(next to the discard button)
- Select Canned Responses
- Select New Canned Response
- Give it a name
- Done

To use a Template:

- Compose a new message
- Click on the more options dropdown
- Select Canned Responses
- Insert your template

Please note: Gmail only allows you to save the body of an email as a template, and not the attachments, but these can be added before sending just as with a normal email.

[Source](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_templates.htm)

Comment: Very helpful ! 

Note that if you attach your file via google drive it's even save your attached file .